# Number of permutations of $S_n$ such that $\sigma^h(a) = \sigma^k(b)$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A basic result in combinatorics is:

> In $S_n$ there are
>
> - $(n-d)(n-2)!$ permutations $\sigma$ such that $\sigma^k(a) = b$, if $a \neq b$;
> - $d(n-1)!$ permutations $\sigma$ such that $\sigma^k(a) = b$, if $a = b$,
>
> where $d$ is the number of positive divisors of $k$.

This lemma makes me wonder:

> In $S_n$ how many permutations $\sigma$ are there such that
>   $$\sigma^k(a) = \sigma^h(b),$$ where $k \neq h$ (and $a = b$ or $a \neq b$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sigma$ is bijective, you can apply $\sigma^{-h}$ to transform this to

$$
\sigma^{k-h}(a)=b\;,
$$

thus reducing it to the result you quoted.

Comment: Of course, you're right! Thanks!